# Is Indexing int better than string in realm for react native?

Tags: react-native, realm

Is querying indexed integers faster than indexed strings in realm?

For example,my documents has about 50 fields, and 10 of them are indexed for query. I'd like to know for fields like `gender`,`race` that have a limited number of options, would you store them as `int` instead of `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, storing small integers in Realm is a good idea. The reason is that Realm compact data. For example, if your values are less than 32, only 5 bits are used. I would probably define the limited number of values as integer constants, and use those though out the code.

Indexing will speed-up queries, but you will use a bit more space and inserts might be a bit slower. But you can say that about any known database :-)